# Questioning the practicality of an idea

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I've had this idea of creating a web application for a while now. It's supposed to be sort of like Google Keep, where you can take notes and add images, except all your data is saved in your browser using IndexedDb.

However, I don't really have a lot of experience with IndexedDb and I don't really know of any of it's possible "dangers" yet. I don't know what I have to prepare for, or if such a web application is even feasible, considering how much space the images or other media would take.

So I wanted to ask for some advice on what to look out for. I'm not expecting a full tutorial or anything like that, but it would help if I could get a little guidance before I pursue this idea.

Would that kind of question be alright, or would it be considered too "open-ended" or otherwise off-topic?

Comment: No.  Just ask what you *really* want to know.  Like "How much data can I expect to store in IndexedDb".  Now it is a plain answerable question with an objective answer.  And above all, Google will tell you before you have to ask.

Answer (score 3):

That kind of question would be inherently too broad and opinionated.

Do some research and development on your own, and when you begin hitting trouble ask about how to deal with those issues.

Stack Overflow is not an appropriate platform to ask for that kind of generic advice.

Comment: Note that ideal way of asking the question "I have trouble with {X}, I tried {A, B, C} but it did not work {because}. I'm looking for help {concrete question}. *Overall I'm trying to do {Z}*". may also indirectly bring guidance on your bigger question if your approach is way off.